# Values ​on one line each after the decimal point. CSV with Python 3+

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file whose structure looks something like this:

```
Name    Nation  Location    URL
Electra European    Luton, Dunstable, Stevenage //ur1l/, //url2/, //url3/
Bob British Bedford, Bedfordshire   //ur1l/, //url21/, //url13/
Lyndi   Thai    Liverpool Street, Street, Goodge Street //ur11l/, //url12/, //url3/
```

[image]

I am trying to access each link separately, but my attempts return each letter separately:

My code:

```
with open('csv/users.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line) #ok
        for link in line[3]:
            print(link) # it's return each letter separately
```

How do you get each link separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields in the file are separated by tabs, and multiple values by `', '` so I doubt that even `line` or `line[3]` contain the values you expect.

You should handle the file accordingly:

```
with open('csv/users.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        for link in line[3].split(', '):
            print(link)
```

BTW, instead of skipping the header row with `next(csv_reader)` and then using unreadable `line[3]`, you can use `DictReader` to be able to access columns by name:

```
import csv

with open('csv/users.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    for line in csv_reader:
        for link in line['URL'].split(', '):
            print(link)
```